# Mandar arquivo texto para o PgAdmin

Tags: java, postgresql, pgadmin

Preciso de uma ajudinha, sou iniciante.Tenho que mandar um arquivo txt que eu abro no netbeans para uma tabela do PgAdmin.

Se vcs verem o código vão me entender. Tentei colocar o meu método que mostra o arquivo txt no INSERT mas n funcionou. Não sei qual a forma correta para fazer isso. a tabela carrega colunas numeric, date e mais 6 numeric. Nessa ordem Agradeço.

```
public class ConexaoTexte {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {

        String url = "jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/teste";
        String usuario = "postgres";
        String senha = "123456";

        Arquivo arquivo = new Arquivo();

        Class.forName("org.postgresql.Driver");

        Connection con;

        con = DriverManager.getConnection(url, usuario, senha);

        System.out.println("Conexão realizada com sucesso.");

        Statement s = con.createStatement();

       //esse metodo "subirArquivo" mostra o meu arquivo texto na tela.
        arquivo.subirArquivo();

          //porem como fazer para inserir ao banco??
        s.executeUpdate("INSERT INTO resultados VALUES ('1','09-11-2016','1','2';'3')");

        con.close();

    } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
        System.out.println("Não foi possível encontrar a Classe!");
    } catch (SQLException ex) {
    }
}
```

}

//a classe para mostrar meu arquivo texto.

public class Arquivo {

```
public void subirArquivo() {

    try (Scanner ler = new Scanner(new File("c:/teste.txt"))) {
        while (ler.hasNext()) {
            System.out.println(ler.nextLine());
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.err.println("Falha ao ler arquivo!");
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Pergunta, você quer mandar o que para o banco de dados? O nome do arquivo apenas? Para depois buscá-lo no banco para dai abrir o arquivo a partir de um diretório específico?

Comment: Ola, já consegui amigo. Era um arquivo com vários nomes e números. Apenas precisei criar um laço de repetição para depois distribuir para as colunas da minha tabela.Vlw

Comment: É interessante você postar uma resposta de como conseguiu resolver o seu problema para que o próximo que tiver essa mesma dificuldade, seja auxiliado pela tua resposta :)

Answer (score 0):

Bom, na minha classe Arquivo, foi criado o método carregarArquivo, que vai ser responsável por mandar meu arquivo txt para um List.

```
public class Arquivo {

public static List<String> carregarArquivo() {
    List<String> t = new ArrayList<>();
    try (Scanner ler = new Scanner(new File("c:/steste.txt"))) {

        while (ler.hasNext()) {
            t.add(ler.nextLine());
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.err.println("Falha ao ler arquivo!");
    }
    return t;
}
```

}

Na classe inserirDados, eu chamo o método carregarArquivo, para poder mandar para o banco.
Antes de mandar para o banco, foi criado um laço de repetição para cada linha do arquivo texto, assim incluo cada um ao INSERT INTO.

```
public class InserirDados {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {

        String url = "jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/teste";
        String usuario = "postgres";
        String senha = "123456";


        Class.forName("org.postgresql.Driver");

        Connection con;

        con = DriverManager.getConnection(url, usuario, senha);

        System.out.println("Conexão realizada com sucesso.");

        Statement s = con.createStatement();
        List<String> arq = Arquivo.carregarArquivo();
        for (String linha : arq) {
            // 1862',01/10/2016',8',49',35',42',56',2
            linha = linha.replaceAll("'", "");
            // 1862,01/10/2016,8,49,35,42,56,2
            String[] p = linha.split(",");

            final String INS = "INSERT INTO resultados (concurso,data,dezena_a) VALUES (%s,'%s',%s)";
            for (int i = 2; i < 8; i++) {
                String script = String.format(INS, p[0], p[1], p[i]);
                s.executeUpdate(script);
            }

        }

        con.close();

    } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
        System.out.println("Não foi possível encontrar a Classe!");
    } catch (SQLException ex) {
    }
}
```

}

Vale lembrar que sou iniciante.Essa foi a forma mais lógica que encontrei para resolver att.